# using python datetime type in BOLT neo4j-driver throws an error. workaround available?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Here is a simplified example of code that I want to run under BOLT and that I was able to execute uner py2neo

```
timeCreated = datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=6, day=15, hour=23)
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "password"))
session = driver.session()
stmt = 'CREATE (y:Year) SET y.timeCreated = {time}'
session.run(stmt, {"time": timeCreated})
```

timeCreated is  python datetime object. I get an error message that a datetime object cannot be used:

```
 ValueError: Values of type <class 'datetime.datetime'> are not supported).
```

Is there a workaround for this? Will it be supported in the future? I'd like to use the BOLT driver and reduce the dependency on py2Neo but it seems that not all functionalities can be transferred yet.

Comment: Node4j has no concept of dates or times as properties of objects; so I doubt there will be support for `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neo4j doesn't natively support datetimes, and I believe py2neo silently converted datetimes into strings in previous versions.

My workaround has been to call the `.isoformat()` method on `datetime` objects to insert them into databases as strings.

Comment: this solved the problem. I prefer this solution over the epoch as it still shows the time character. the epoch is just a number

Comment: This helps me too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Node4j has no concept of dates or times as properties of objects; so I doubt there will be support for `datetime` type. You should store the epoch value instead:

```
import calendar
import time

epoch = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
```